# Anonymous proxy over SSL

Tags: encryption, privacy, proxy, anonymity

Can you name any anonymous proxy software that don't use VPN connections? Basically, I'm analyzing different encrypted traffic and now I need to analyse a simple anonymity proxy traffic. I'm analyzing from the client side (my own traffic).

I need something like HotSpot Shield but that doesn't use VPN connections otherwise I can't capture the traffic.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, and welcome to [security.se]. Please see the [FAQ], and [ask] - this question was closed since product recommendations are not a good fit for SE.

Answer (score 1):

An obvious choice is [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/). It's an encrypted anonymity network, popular with the likes of Anonymous and blackhat groups.

[Freenet](https://freenetproject.org/) is a similar network, though it's designed primarily for transferral of information within the Freenet network, rather than accessing normal web services in an anonymous fashion.

Alternatively, you could look into normal SOCKS proxies, including SSL proxies. You can find an abundance of them on [HideMyAss](http://hidemyass.com/proxy-list/).

Comment: oh I forgot to mention that Tor I had analysed Tor already. What I need is a SSL proxy software which I can install on my computer. Something non-web based..

Comment: in fact, a normal SOCKs proxy or SSL proxy from HideMyAss would work. But the problem is that, I need all the traffic to be encrypted and apparently the requests are not encrypted just the payload (data).

Comment: @user1454263 Take a look at Freenet then.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an SSL proxy you can run either locally or on another computer http://mitmproxy.org/